# Хулиганы в сообществе

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

Буквально минут 10-20 назад наткнулся на хулигана, который писал всякую чушь вроде "могилы Ленина" и отвечал не самыми приятными ответами. Как с такими бороться, и что делать?

Comment: тревога -> невежливый или оскорбительный на ответе или вопросе - придут модераторы и накажут

Comment: @PashaPash, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy так ответы же дорогие. В пять раз дороже комментария. Не каждый может себе позволить.

Comment: @Grundy за ответы на мете не дают репутацию

Comment: [Что делать, если я вижу как кто-то нарушает правила?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

Comment: @Grundy что значит почему не ответом?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На каждом сообщении или комментарии на сайтах сети Stack Exchange имеется возможность поставить признак тревоги, выбрав соответствующий тип и в некоторых случаях даже снабдить тревогу дополнительным поясняющим сообщением. Тревоги периодически обрабатываются модераторами, и если проблема действительно имеет место быть, то будут приняты соответствующие меры. Состояние выставленной тревоги вы можете контролировать в своем профиле по клику на сообщение с количеством полезных тревог:

> [image: тревоги]

Подробнее о том, как работают тревоги, можно почитать в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).